# Twitter site-streams

Tags: api, twitter

I would like to use the twitter site-streams but I can't find a way to use them. There is no API-docs online and how to access site-streams.

Does someon have an example in php or better c#?

Are there any API-samples or a full API-doc?

Thanks
Matthias

Answer (score 1):

I called [oAuth](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2011/11/authpack-provides-net-oauth-for-twitter-facebook-linkedin-and-google/) before doing something similar to Shannon Whitley's [user streams](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2010/04/open-source-net-c-twitter-streaming-api-client/) example.   Use the curl commands generated for you at dev.twitter.com to double check your C# generate urls.

The site stream url is buried in the top middle of the doc (/2b/site.json?follow=1,2,3,4,5) @ dev.twitter.com

I'd also follow @sitestreams as well to get heads up on site stream restarts.

Answer (score 0):

The API looks to still be in beta, I found [this](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/site_streams).  It's not a lot of detail, but the post was only a few weeks ago so it is something pretty new.  It uses the same REST API that all of twitter uses so if you are familiar with that you should be able to use what it gives you.

If you need a tutorial on REST with twitter [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2008/11/15/twitter-api-from-c-getting-a-user-s-time-line.aspx) is a decent tutorial.  It is using basic authentication so I do strongly recommend that you use [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/basic_to_oauth) instead.